# How to connect with ODP.NET Core to Oracle 9i database - Managed Driver

Tags: oracle, odp.net, asp.net-core-2.1, oracle9i, odp.net-managed

When i try to connect to  Oracle 9i db, i get always ORA-1017 invalid username/password; logon denied.
On Oracle 10g or higher all is well.

ODP.NET Core: 2.18.3; 
ASP.NET Core: 2.1.403

ConnectionString: "Data Source=myTnsName;password=myPassword;user id=myUserId"

TnsAdmin is set.

In Oracle log on db side i found this entry: ORA-1017 invalid username/password; Unknown Auth type: 6A

Any ideas are welcome? It is possible to connect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, Oracle database below 10.2 is not supported. See [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/InstallSystemRequirements.htm#ODPNT149):

> **System Requirements**
>
> Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver requires the following:
>
> - Same Windows operating system support as ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver.
> - ODP.NET, Managed Driver is built with AnyCPU. It runs on either 32-bit or 64-bit (x64) Windows and on either 32-bit or 64-bit (x64) .NET Framework.
> - Microsoft .NET Framework 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, or 4.5.2
> - **Access to Oracle Database 10g Release 2 or later**